# Locally connectedness and accessibility in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: gn.general-topology, cv.complex-variables, complex-dynamics

Suppose $\Omega$ to be a bounded area in the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$ with a locally connected boundary $\partial\Omega$, then every point of $\partial\Omega$ is accessible from Ω.Here accessibility of a point $\omega_0\in\Omega$ means that there exists a continuous mapping $\alpha:[0,1)\to\Omega$ such that $ \lim\limits_{t\to1^-}\alpha(t)=\omega_0$.

Actually this proposition is part of the proof of the Caratheodory Theorem of comformal mapping which states: If $f:B_1(0)\to\Omega$ is a comformal mapping and $\Omega$ is a bounded simply connected area, then the following two are equivalent:

(1)$f$ can be extended to a continuous surjective map $\overline{B_1(0)}\to\overline{\Omega}$

(2)$\partial\Omega$ is locally connected

Of course, if we assume that the Caratheodory Theorem of comformal mapping has already been proven, then the proposition I asked above can also be solved by applying the Theorem. However, as I have said above, the proposition is used in the proof of Caratheodory Theorem of comformal mapping (more exactly, this proposition is used to prove surjectivity), so I am looking for a topological proof or any proof without using the Caratheodory Theorem. I have already searched for some resourses of the proof of the Caratheodory Theorem, but most of them either deal with the case that $\partial\Omega$ is a Jordan curve, or simply omit the proof that $f$ is a surjective map.

Any hint or help is highly appreciated.

Comment: This is Theorem 14.4. in Newman - elements of the topology of plane sets of points

Comment: I don't think the Theorem 14.4 in Newman book is talking about the same thing as I posted. It states that if $D$ is locally connected at $a$, where $a$ is a boundary point of $D$, then $a$ is accessible from $D$. However, in my post, I do not assume that $a\in D$, and it's not hard to give a counterexample if we replace the requirement that $\partial D$ is locally connected everywhere with it is locally connected at a point $a\in \partial D$ @erz

Comment: ok, i see what you mean, sorry for a wrong reference. Check out Rempe-Gillen - On prime ends and local connectivity, I think he discusses something along these lines there